# webservice In Iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone

i have downloaded WSDLObjC-0.6 from google to enable SOAP webservice in IPhone SDK.But is is as App file,how can i integrate that file to iphone SDK and to use SOAP webservice?
Any help please?(Tutorial says to Integrate This)

Comment: I assume you're referring to this project: http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the [usage instructions](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) for the project?  Also, pay attention to the string of comments at the bottom of that page.